# Filling a form through casperjs with phantomjs causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, e2e-testing

In built process I have JS e2e tests running with casperjs and phantomjs. After updating to the latest versions (phantomjs-prebuilt: 2.1.12, casperjs: 1.1.3) I get the following error when I try fill the form:

```
FAIL Unable to fill form: TypeError: Function.caller used to retrieve strict caller
type: uncaughtError
file: tests/js/e2e/dummyTest.js:815
error: Unable to fill form: TypeError: Function.caller used to retrieve strict caller
       fillForm@phantomjs://platform/casper.js:815:79
       fillSelectors@phantomjs://platform/casper.js:912:25
       phantomjs://code/dummyTest.js:170:27
       runStep@phantomjs://platform/casper.js:1615:31
       checkStep@phantomjs://platform/casper.js:406:28
stack: not provided
```

Here is a simple example of test code:

```
casper.test.begin("Dummy test", function suite(test) {

    casper.start('http://www.heureka.cz/', function() {
        casper.echo('Page loaded: ' + this.getTitle());

        this.fillForm('form#f_search', { // same effect/problem with fill method
            'h[fraze]':    'test'
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

I found that the error is caused by this function in `clientutils.js:691` in casperjs:

```
this.log = function log(message, level) {
    console.log("[casper:" + (level || "debug") + "] " + message);
};
```

With phantomjs v1.9.20 everything works fine.

Comment: `casper.fillForm` is an undocumented internal function. You should really use one of the documented functions that do the same thing.

Comment: @ArtjomB.It has same effect no matter if I use `fill` or `fillForm` method. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried  this.fillSelectors ??

Comment: @Rippo I tried this method and it threw same error.